# Why does Laravel change the value of cookie for every request?

Tags: php, laravel, security, session, cookies

I understand that the session_id need to be regenerated after user login to prevent session fixation attack. And the session_id need to be a random string to prevent attacked to brute force it.

So Laravel need something to encrypt the session_id.

But why Laravel choose encryption over hashing for session_id?

I check the documentation that Laravel use AES encryption for session.

But still, Why Laravel choose an encryption method that produces a different value every time after session_id being encrypted?

What is wrong with the encryption method that produces a fixed value for session_id, and then set it for that cookie?

Why the cookie value of the session_id is changed every time for a new request?

Comment: Laravel needs to be able to decrypt the session_id which it wouldn't be able to do if t was a hash.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense now. But I wonder what is the use of MAC(message authentication code) here. Which part of the Encryption/Decryption process involves the HMAC method. Did HMAC hash the original session data with APP_KEY or it hashes the encrypted session data with APP_KEY ? If the data was hashed (or signed) by HMAC, it did prevent client modification, but how can you reverse the hash value to get the original session data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not just related to Laravel but it's more like `Dynamic` encryption vs `Static` encryption irrespective of language and framework.

You can encrypt a value but you can't de-hash a hash value. As the data is going to be used later on, we keep it encrypted so that it can be de-crypted later on.

> Dynamic Encryption provides extra protection, as not only the encryption keys but also the configuration of the crypto system change for each data transfer. The inner encryption algorithm (e.g. AES-256 or national algorithm) is wrapped by an outer Dynamic Encryption algorithm. When the data transfer is complete, the encryption algorithm is discarded, which leaves no way of introducing master keys for data inspection.

`Cryptanalysis` (code breaking) normally requires large amounts of data to be encrypted with the same method. As Dynamic Encryption is constantly mutating, cryptanalysis is made practically impossible.

[Here](https://www.dencrypt.dk/dynamic-encryption/) is a good read about why dynamic encryption is being used.

Comment: So the value of the session cookie is not a hash value. So that tt can be decrypted when it is sent back to the server. But Laravel mentioned it use HMAC to prevent AES encrypted value from client tempering. I wonder which part HMAC takes in.

Answer (score 1):

I accepted Danyal Sandeelo's answer.

The value of the cookie is encrypted,
which contains 2 things--session_id and the HMAC hashed string.

The HMAC-hashed string is hashed on the server using APP_KEY: 
HMAC(the session_id, the APP_KEY ). Then the server use AES to encrypt it and send it to the client side.

AES encryption produces different ciphertexts even with the same plaintext using the same key.

When the encrypted value of cookie is sent back to the backend, 
the server will first decrypt it to get the session_id and the HMAC hashed string.
Then it will use the APP_KEY to HMAC-hash session_id to see the outcome value match the return HMAC hashed string or not.

If it didn't match, then that means the session_id is tampered by the client side.

And the value of session cookie is changed for every request, it is because AES encryption produces different ciphertexts even with the same plaintext using the same key.

Answer (score 0):

The driver used matters here.

The `cookie` driver stores all information inside the cookie and thus Laravel needs to be able to decrypt that value to read it and the value changes every time because the session is modified each request resulting in different data being encrypted and thus the encrypted string you see in the cookie is different each request.

However when using the file driver (or any other driver than file or array) Laravel still needs to be able to read the plain text session ID (so encryption not hashing) to look it up in the data store but stores the data in a file/database/redis which should keep the cookie value the same for the duration of the session since the session ID doesn't change.

Read more about all the drivers and where the data is stored in de [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session#configuration).

Answer (score -2):

Laravel changes it Because of privacy.....